# Problem with table cell autolayout not spacing the way I want

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to put a table cell that I designed into my table view which is supposed to show an artists songs, album pictures, as well as a play button but I'm not able to get the layout correct the way that I want it.

Screenshot of current app layout:

[image]

I want all the play buttons flush to the right of the table view but it seems like it disregards the constraints I put in the table view and goes out of bounds. I also want the extra space that the label has (shown in picture linked below) so that it spaces throughout the whole cell so that the play button can be to the right of the table view cell.

Current table view cell:

[image]

Here is the picture of my view controller layout and the constraints I put on them. Let me know if there is anything I can do and change. Thanks.

View controller layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it programmatically, for this example I set numberOfRowsInSection to return 20, set objects in your UITableViewCell class:

```
let containerViw: UIView = {
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    return myView
}()

lazy var buttonPlay: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "play.circle")
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlay), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   
    return button
}()

let dummyLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Dummy Label"
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    label.textColor = .black
    
    return label
}()

let finestraBackground: UIImageView = {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    return imageView
}()
```

now in UITableViewCell.CellStyle set stackView and add Constraints:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    backgroundColor = .white
    
    containerViw.addSubview(buttonPlay)
    buttonPlay.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerViw.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerViw.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [finestraBackground, dummyLabel, containerViw])
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

last step set the function for play:

```
@objc fileprivate func handlePlay() {
    print("Play...")
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

full code:

```
class TableViewCellCustom: UITableViewCell {

let containerViw: UIView = {
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    return myView
}()

lazy var buttonPlay: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "play.circle")
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlay), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   
    return button
}()

let dummyLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Dummy Label"
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    label.textColor = .black
    
    return label
}()

let finestraBackground: UIImageView = {
    
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    return imageView
}()

@objc fileprivate func handlePlay() {
    print("Play...")
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
    backgroundColor = .white
    
    containerViw.addSubview(buttonPlay)
    buttonPlay.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerViw.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonPlay.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerViw.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [finestraBackground, dummyLabel, containerViw])
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

**UPDATE**, create tableView programmatically example with a top view, without storyboard

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let cellId = "cellId"
let tableView = UITableView()

let containerView = UIView()
let dummyImageView = UIImageView()
let artistLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    artistLabel.text = "Artist Name\nArtist Song Name"
    artistLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
    artistLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    artistLabel.textColor = .white
    
    dummyImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    dummyImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    dummyImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    dummyImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dummyImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    dummyImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    dummyImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    
    containerView.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    tableView.register(TableViewCellCustom.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [dummyImageView, artistLabel])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    containerView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 120
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellCustom
    
    return cell
}
}
```

in scene delegate activate navigation controller like this:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    //        let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())//if you want navigation controller uncomment that
    let controller = ViewController() // if you want navigation Controller COMMENT That
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = controller
}
```

Or you can use didSelecrRowAt method:
just add this two lines in your TableViewController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Play...", indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Do I then delete the table cell that I designed and keep it blank instead? I deleted it and then tried to do it programmatically but then when the table view loaded, the cells were not created.

Comment: I update my answer with an example for how you can create a table view with a custom tableViewCell programmatically without storyboard... Create a new project and try it, copy and paste view controller class, create a new file and copy and paste custom cell, if my answer was exhaustive please check it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! However, the window that I'm presenting is not the root view controller rather a view that I'm presenting modally. Is there a way I can still have a title at the top as well as a UI Image View for the picture of the artist as well?

Comment: I update table view code with a container view and a stackView with an Image view and label inside on top Take a look, in the scene delegate I comment navigation controller and add a simply controller... :)

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant to say is the view with the artist name and the table view and table cells is not a view I want to present right when the app launches, rather it is only triggered when a button is pressed which is then presented modally. As of now, the table cells load however, the artist image and name do not because the view is not presented right when the app launches.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well, copy and paste the code of the table again, I modified it ... As for the modal presentation, just rename MY ViewController class with another name (es: ArtistController) and use YOUR ViewController with the call action button...

Comment: Hi again, is there a way to add like a label on top of the tableview that says "Popular Songs"?  I wanted to add it so it gives it a bit of context as to what the tableview is displaying. I've tried doing it myself but I haven't been successful. Thanks

Comment: @raymanan11Hi, add this method with a label inside: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Popular Songs"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        label.textColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
        return label
    }

Comment: @raymanan11after that call height for heather in section like this: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    } and that's all

Comment: Hi, long time no see! I recently ran into a problem where I'm using my iPad and the pla button works when I press it but when I switch to my iPhone (iPhone X), the buttons are unable to be pressed. I was wondering whether you had this issue on your end too and if it would be a problem with the auto layout constraints?

Comment: @raymanan11 try to add didSelectRowAt, I put in my last update...

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved without code.

Just set `Content Compression Resistance Priority` to 1000 for your "Play Button" and `Content Hugging Priority` to be higher than your "Song Name" label like 251 for button and 250 for label.

Answer (score 0):

You have given the constraints incorrectly as I can see, You can change the constraints of the play button with trailing to the superview and giving it carter vertically to superview. And Remove leading from the button if any this will make it on the right side of the cell view.

And giving the image View as top and bottom and leading constraints to superView and make the height constant for the superView or the cellView.

Then making the label leading constraint to ImageView and center vertically with the image view/superView. And give the label trailing to the button a fixed contact like only 10. And you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

I think it’s because you have putted PlayButton inside your StackView.
StackView Automatically putts your components side by side.
Try putting your Play Button out of StackView and add Constraints for both stackView and PlayButton.